# How to deal with a flaw in System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable()

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, extension-methods

I've come across something which is perhaps a flaw in the Extension method `.CopyToDataTable`.

This method is used by Importing (in VB.NET) `System.Data.DataTableExtensions` and then calling the method against an IEnumerable. You would do this if you want to filter a Datatable using LINQ, and then restore the DataTable at the end.

i.e:

```
Imports System.Data.DataRowExtensions
    Imports System.Data.DataTableExtensions

    Public Class SomeClass
            Private Shared Function GetData() As DataTable
                Dim Data As DataTable

                Data = LegacyADO.NETDBCall


                Data = Data.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(dr) dr.Field(Of Integer)("SomeField") = 5).CopyToDataTable()


                Return Data

            End Function
    End Class
```

In the example above, the "WHERE" filtering might return no results. If this happens CopyToDataTable throws an exception because there are no DataRows.

Why?

The correct behavior should be to return a DataTable with Rows.Count = 0.

Can anyone think of a clean workaround to this, in such a way that whoever calls CopyToDataTable doesn't have to be aware of this issue?

System.Data.DataTableExtensions is a Static Class so I can't override the behavior. Any ideas? Have I missed something?

UPDATE:

I have submitted this as an issue to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=422727). I would still like some suggestions, but if you agree with me, you could vote up the issue at Connect via the link above

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until Microsoft fix this issue, here's a work around:

Create your own Extension method which uses the CopyToDataTable method if there are DataRows, if there aren't, then it returns an empty DataTable.

VB.NET

```
    Imports System.Data

Namespace CustomExtensions
    Public Module DataRowExtensionsOverride

        <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Function CopyToDataTableOverride(Of T As DataRow)(ByVal Source As EnumerableRowCollection(Of T)) As DataTable

            If Source.Count = 0 Then
                Return New DataTable
            Else
                Return DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(Of DataRow)(Source)
            End If

        End Function

    End Module
End Namespace
```

C#;

```
public static class DataRowExtensionsOverride
    {

        public static DataTable CopyToDataTableOverride<T>(this IEnumerable<T> Source) where T : DataRow {

            if (Source.Count() == 0) {
                return new DataTable();
            } else {
                return DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(Source);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that this could be slightly improved to use `!Source.Any()` instead of `Source.Count() == 0`. `Any` will stop as soon as it finds any results.

Comment: This is not a bug; the behavior is very much by design and deliberate.  One of the first things `CopyToDataTable` does is grab a row, find the underlying table, and copy the columns into your new `DataTable`. Your workaround creates an empty `DataTable` with no columns.  You can get away with this in a DataSource (it won't look at the table if it has no rows), but in other scenarios you cannot.

Answer (score 12):

```
someDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("SomeField") == "SomeValue").AsDataView().ToTable();
```

`.AsDataView().ToTable()` returns an empty table with the same structure as `someDataTable` if there are now rows returned from `.Where()`

Comment: one issue i see with your custom extension is the check for .Count.  If i'm not mistaken, .Count forces the a read of the entire enumeration.  Therefore, if your count is say, 1000, then you're reading the entire enumeration then calling CopyToDataTable() which probably forces another read.  Have you considered checking if .GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == true?  If this is true, then the enumeration has at least one row, and that's all your concerned about, not the count.

Comment: good point vince, you're totally right. I'll update it, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem today and worked out a [workaround](http://dommyzee.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-get-row-count-for.html) if it helps.

Sorry, but the blog is in C#, but I just used an IEnumerable on the LINQ variable and check .Current to see if it had returned any rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable SearchDT = (DataTable)ViewState["SearchDT"];
DataTable NewDT = SearchDT.Select("BSerialNo='" + SerialNo + "' and BBranch='" + Branch + "' and Warehouse='" + WareHouse + "' and Buffer_ModelNo='" + PartNo + "'").CopyToDataTable();
//  first get an array of DataRows '
if ((NewDT.Rows.Count > 0))
{
    //first check to see if the array has rows
    DataTable dt = NewDT;
    PopUpGrdView.DataSource = dt;
    PopUpGrdView.DataBind();
    //dt now exists and contains rows
}
```