# DataTable RowFilter avoid Source contains no data rows Exception

Tags: asp.net, datatable

im using following code to get a filtered DataTable

```
DT = NewMobileFa.GetNewMobile().AsEnumerable().Where(r => arrList.Contains(r.Field<int>("NewMobileID")) && r.Field<string>("Status") == "OF").CopyToDataTable();
```

this code gives me the error

```
Source contains no data rows
```

which is correct and actually there is no data

what i need is,i need to avoid the exception if there are no data rows and just to return the empty DataSource.

can i achieve this?

Comment: What framework version are you using? This seemed to be fixed in .NET 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636765/how-to-deal-with-a-flaw-in-system-data-datatableextensions-copytodatatable

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. first you need to get all the rows. then check for count  of the retrived rows. you can check [MSDN DataTable.CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx), it has nice explanation

```
var Rows = NewMobileFa.GetNewMobile().AsEnumerable().Where(r => arrList.Contains(r.Field<int>("NewMobileID")) && r.Field<string>("Status") == "OF");
```

Now use the rows to check whether data is there or not

```
if(Rows.Count()>0)
{
   DataTable dt = Rows.CopyToDataTable(); 
}
```

Comment: But i don't get an exception with `tbl.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>1==2).CopyToDataTable()`. It will successfully create a DataTable with 0 rows whether or not source DataTable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in 4.0 although it's not marked so.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/422727/major-flaw-in-system-data-datatableextensions-copytodatatable-design

A quick test on 4.0 works as expected:

```
tbl.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>1==2).CopyToDataTable();
```

It will successfully create a DataTable with 0 rows whether or not source DataTable is empty.

If you are using an older version of the .NET framework, use one of its overloads like [CopyToDataTable(IEnumerable, DataTable, LoadOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359707%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which don't throw an exception if there are no rows in the source `DataTable`.

Or use one of the suggested approaches here:

[How to deal with a flaw in System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636765/how-to-deal-with-a-flaw-in-system-data-datatableextensions-copytodatatable)