# VB.Net LINQ Get Field Names when no rows

Tags: linq, vb.net-2010

I have a LINQ query on a couple of DataTables as follows:

```
query = _
            From bidInfo In dataset.BidInfo.AsEnumerable() _
            Join projectInfo In dataset.ProjectInfo.AsEnumerable() _
            On projectInfo.Field(Of String)("Project") Equals bidInfo.Field(Of String)("Project") _
            Where Not bidInfo.IsAwardedNull AndAlso bidInfo.Awarded.Equals("Yes") And Not bidInfo.IsDate_AwardedNull AndAlso DateTime.Compare(bidInfo.Item("Date Awarded"), latestCheck) >= 0 _
            Select New With { _
                .Job_Number = projectInfo.Field(Of Object)("Job Number"), _
                .Project = projectInfo.Field(Of String)("Project"), _
                .Contractor = bidInfo.Field(Of String)("Contractor"), _
                .Date = Convert.ToDateTime(bidInfo.Field(Of Object)("Date Awarded"))}
```

I put the results in a DataView table and then sort and other stuff. This all works well except for when the query doesn't return anything (because there isn't anything that matches the criteria, that's fine). If it doesn't return any rows then the resulting DataTable doesn't generate columns, which is not acceptable.

Is there any way to dynamically get what columns SHOULD be returned by the query? I have a bunch of queries, and it would be horribly messy if I created a static DataTable for each one. There's probably a very easy solution that I just haven't been able to find yet.

Thank you for any help!

**EDIT:**

I have marked Neolisk's answer as the answer because it explains why I have the problem I have (and it shows that I pretty much duplicated a question). However, the problem isn't actually solved. If I figure out a decent solution then I'll post it here in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Seems like you solved the issue using the link I provided in my answer, is that correct? If so, please remove the EDIT part, or at least say it's solved now or something.

Comment: I haven't actually solved the issue. Your answer explained why it doesn't work, but there doesn't seem to be a way to actually get the columns if there are no rows. On that note, is there a way to set the question as unresolved but done with? If not I'll set it as solved.

Comment: Did you try either of the two answers through the link I provided? Both would seem to solve your problem.

Comment: The workaround that Andy posts and marks as the answer just returns an empty DataTable. It looks like Vince's answer would work, but I couldn't get it to work when joining multiple tables (which is the main reason I'm using LINQ).

Comment: Isn't an empty DataTable exactly what you want?

Comment: No, I want a DataTable that has the columns. The empty DataTable has 0 columns, but I need the columns that the LINQ would have returned had there been rows =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use CopyToDataTable like this:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

And then use `dt` for data binding. Reference:

- [Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:** Actually, it used to break in previous versions of .NET, complaining about null input, not sure about the latest one, but there is a `.AsDataView().ToTable()` workaround:

- [How to deal with a flaw in System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636765/how-to-deal-with-a-flaw-in-system-data-datatableextensions-copytodatatable)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am using a special type of CopyToDataTable (it's actually called SpecialCopyToDataTable =P) that I found on a forum for dealing with anonymous enumerable stuff. It works great, when the LINQ returns rows it copies the query to a DataTable exactly how I'd like. The problem is when there are no rows returned by the query the DataTable it generates does not have any columns. I'm trying to find a way to get the columns that are supposed to be generated.

Comment: Hey, so I actually properly looked at the link you linked and it deals with it, so thank you for that =D